# Is a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ dominated by a Ball?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a smooth projective variety of dimension $d$ over the complex numbers.

Is it true that there is a ball $\Delta_d=\{ z\in \mathbb{C}^d / \lvert z\rvert<1\}$ and a *surjective* holomorphic (possibly ramified) morphism
$$f:\Delta_d\longrightarrow X?$$
This is true if $X$ is:

1. a curve;
2. the $d$-dimensional projective space;
3. an Abelian variety.
4. A ball quotient.

And every variety dominated by these.

And same question but replacing $\Delta_d$ with $\Delta_1\times\dots\times\Delta_1$ ($d$ times).

Comment: Why is an arbitrary abelian variety dominated by a ball?

Comment: take a ball in the universal cover which strictly contains a fundamental domain

Comment: This paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373992 seems to prove a much stronger result if instead of a ball you use a polydisk: every complex manifold is the image of a polydisk under a finite mapping.  They also show the degree of the mapping can be bounded in terms of the dimension of the manifold.

Comment: @Jack Huizenga: But "finite" and "degree" are not the right terms. The preimage of every point is finite, but the cardinality may vary. The manifold is not assumed compact (though of course it must be connected). And the map is locally invertible!

Comment: Fair enough, I was being a little sloppy.

Comment: @Jack Huizenga: thanks a lot! this is exactly the kind of result I was looking for!